# Javascript to check page url, and then load corresponding iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Can I get some pointers on a problem I've encountered please?

**Short version**

Does anyone know whether i can use javascript to load a specific iframe depending on the name of the parent page:

If page name = "http://www.example.com/products/pens" , iframe content = pens.htm

If page name = "http://www.example.com/products/electronics" , iframe content = electronics.htm

**More info**

I need to improve the navigation of a ecommerce store, its an off the shelf setup, where you can only brand and restyle the store using css and a bit of javascript, or insert HTML blocks. There's around 14 parent categories, and about ten subcategories within each one.

I would like to add an auto height iframe html block into the category page template, and use it to show a list of subcategories and images.

Is there some javascript i can use to detect the category page name, and then load the corresponding iframe?

I would like to use one HTML block, and have ten iframes for it to load depending on the parent page name.

Any help is much appreciated

Dave

Comment: If it is a cookie cutter store, like say Magento, then I would tag it that way to get better assistance modifying it to better suit your needs.

Comment: Pretty much what you ask for but there is probably a better solution `myIframe.src = window.location.pathname.replace(/^.*\//, '') + '.html';`

Comment: Hi Cole thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately its not a mainstream ecommerce platform, it may even be a custom build for that company.

Answer (score 1):

You can point your iframe to an initial "picker" page... and then in there, check the parent's location and then do a redirect.

For example:

This would be in the category pages.

```
<iframe src="Picker.htm"></iframe>
```

This would be the contents of "Picker.htm"

```
<script type="text/javascript">

switch (parent.location.href.toLowerCase())
{
    case "http://www.example.com/products/pens":
        location.href = "pens.htm";
        break;

    case "http://www.example.com/products/electronics":
        location.href = "electronics.htm";
        break;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if either 'pens' or 'electronics' is in the pathname and change the iframe source accordingly:

```
if (window.location.pathname.match('pens')) {
    $('iframe').attr('src', 'pens.htm');
    // document.getElementById('id').src = 'pens.htm'; // 'id' = id of iframe
    // or, if iframe has no id, use document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'), etc.
} else if (window.location.pathname.match('electronics')) {
    $('iframe').attr('src', 'electronics.htm');
    // document.getElementById('id').src = 'electronics.htm';
}
```

**Edit:** Since jQuery is allowed, I've commented out the native-JS answers and used jQuery

Answer (score 0):

you can check your main `document.location` and set the `src` attribute of your `iframe` accordingly. is that what you are looking for?

Comment: `document.location` is non-standard and deprecated, use `window.location` or simply `location` as the global scope is accessible from any scope due to lexical scope chain (except when one shadows the global `location` object, then again `window.location` can be used)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('/products/pens') > 0){
$('#iframeid').attr('src', '/pens.html');
} else if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('/products/electronics') > 0){
$('#iframeid').attr('src', '/electronics.html');
}
```

or if the iframe does not exist on the page, you can add it through jquery:

```
if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('/products/pens') > 0){
   $('.iframePlaceHolder').append('<iframe src="pens.htm" />');
} else if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('/products/electronics') > 0){
   $('.iframePlaceHolder').append('<iframe src="electronics.htm" />');
}
```

If you are not using JQuery, you can do the following the add the iframes:

```
var newIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('/products/pens') > 0){
    newIframe.src = "pens.htm";
} else if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('/products/electronics') > 0){
    newIframe.src = "electronics.htm";
}
document.getElementById('idOfPlaceHolder').appendChild(newIframe);
```

Comment: I find it really interesting  that my answer was downvoted almost immediately (not joking, downvoted in less than two seconds). If there are real issues with this answer I would love to know about them, as I use this code in very similar circumstances very frequently.

Comment: I'm guessing it might be because you answered a JavaScript question with jQuery when it wasn't tagged as such?

Comment: Hi hnafar, thanks for the code im a real beginner at javascript, but its seems like a good solution & will give it a try.  Is it possible to set the height of the iframe from within this code, or is auto height on the '#iframeid' a better method?

Comment: @DaveBillingsly, are you loading jQuery on your site. If not, this answer will not work, but if you are I can edit your tags to reflect that.

Comment: @ Derek, I think the backend supports both jquery and javascript, if the topic hasn't been covered before, it may be worth upadting the tag for others to use as a guide if you don't mind

Comment: Please see my edit regarding doing this without JQuery as @DerekHenderson kindly noted (several times) that you may not be using JQuery on your page.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, i've never encountered such helpfulness on forums before. Im not too hot on the coding side, so it will take me some time tomorrow to work throught the solutions.  Thanks again guys